# Average a difference in timestamps across all rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like so:

```
id |  username   |  jointime  | parttime
------------------------------------------
1  |     foo     | 1391806818 | 1391814383
2  |     bar     | 1391406218 | 1392714270
3  |     baz     | 1391327818 | 1393197383
4  |     qux     | 1391815603 | 1391818320
```

I would like to find the **overall** average time that's being spent on the site (parttime - jointime).

I tried a query like the one below, but it just returned the average time spent by one single user.

```
SELECT AVG(parttime - jointime) as time FROM foo_table
```

Any ideas as to how I can get the overall average difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already getting what you want.

Using your example data, result is:

```
796974.75
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d94977/1/0

That is the average of the 4 differences in your example data:

```
7565
1308052
1869565
2717
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d94977/2/0

It is not the average of one particular user, but indeed the average of all sessions (stored on the table), which I believe is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap that in a SUM.

```
SELECT SUM(AVG(parttime - jointime)) as time FROM foo_table
```